# using a variable inside a nested function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using a variable inside the nested function and after assigning a value pass to the parent function but on calling it shows nothing.

```
function userexists(key) {
  let user = false;
  UsersModel.findOne({ email: key }, function (error, foundUser) {
    if (!error && foundUser) user = foundUser;
    else {
      console.log("error or not found: " + error);
    }
  });

  return user;
}
```

Comment: The reason for that is that `findOne` seems to be an async function. Therefore `user` is always false. Make sure to `async await` or a callback function in the function itself.

Comment: so in this situation, what should I suppose to do?

Comment: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that findOne seems to be an async function. Therefore `user` is always `false`. Make sure to `async await` or add a callback function in the function itself.

Example async await, if possible:

```js
async function abc(key) {
  const response = await UsersModel.findOne({ email: key });
  if (response.error)
    return false;
  }

  return response.foundUser;
}
```

Example callback function:

```js
function async abc(key, f) {
  UsersModel.findOne({ email: key }, (error, foundUser) => {
    if (!error) f();
  });
}
```

Comment: In the first example, it says await is only valid in async function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [FloWy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8401261/flowy) and [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz)

Before,

```
function userexists(key) {
  let user = false;
  UsersModel.findOne({ email: key }, function (error, foundUser) {
    if (!error && foundUser) user = foundUser;
    else {
      console.log("error or not found: " + error);
    }
  });

  return user;
}
```

Using callback inside a function,

```
function userexists(key, callback) {
  UsersModel.findOne({ email: key }, function (error, foundUser) {
    if (!error && foundUser) return callback(foundUser);
    else return callback(false);
  });
}
```

On Call,

```
userexists(username, function (user) {
// you can use user here
});
```